# Laravel 7: Match two column dates with current date and show value depends on the condition

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

Leave:

| id | user_id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2022-06-01 | 2022-06-03 |

Blade:

```
@foreach ($users as $row )
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
        <td>{{ $row->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $row->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $row->dpt->department }}</td>
        @php
           $today = Carbon\Carbon::now();
           $leave = App\Leave::where('user_id', $row->id)->whereBetween('') <!-- incomplete -->


         @endphp
         <td>Leave Status</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

In this table, all user lists are shown. Here in the Leave Status column, it will show `On Leave` if the user is on leave today. I think I have to match today's date with `start_date` and `end_date` of the leave table and also match the `user_id`

What will be the eloquent query for this?

Example:

| id | name | Leave Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jhon | Present |
| 2 | Doe | On Leave |
| 3 | Laura | On Leave |

Comment: You can try: $leave = App\Leave::where('user_id', $row->id)->where('start_date', '<=',$today)->where('end_date', '>=',$today);

Comment: You can try: 
$today_date = Carbon\Carbon::now();
$today = $today_date->toDateString();
$leave = App\Leave::where('user_id', $row->id)->where('start_date', '<=',$today)->where('end_date', '>=',$today);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you also have the relationships defined in the model you could load them with [constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads) in your controller:

```php
$users = User::with(['leaves' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('start_date', '>=', Carbon::now()))
          ->where('end_date', '<=', Carbon::now()));
}])->get();
```

This way you don't have to query in your blade templates and you can just check if `count($row->leaves) > 0`

Answer (score 0):

have you try this:

```
\Carbon\Carbon::now()->between($row->leaves()->last()->start_date,$row->leaves()->last()->end_date) ? 'On Leave' : 'Present';
```

Comment: Where I match the user? Can you please make the answer more specific